# I Reinstall XAMPP but I can't create DB with same name

Tags: mysql, xampp

1. I have uninstalled XAMPP
2. I installed it again
3. First I had a DB named 'xyz'. After I reinstalled XAMPP, the DB is normally deleted but here the problem started...
4. When I try to create a database with same named 'xyz', I can create it, but if I try to create for example 'cities' table in 'xyz' DB, MySQL gives an error and it blocks me. **Because I had the cities table before I uninstalled XAMPP.**

If the DB is not deleted, where is it? If it is deleted, why can't I create the cities table?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Uninstalling XAMPP or any other virtual web server on a windows machine, there remains a folder which includes databases and other files like logs and etc. 
After Uninstalling go to where you installed (in my case c:wamp ) and delete any remaining files if you dont need them, if you need the databases, do not delete them.

Comment: There was only my project's files. In phpMyAdmin window db is not showing but when i try to create it, it it saying to me "it is already exist"

Comment: try deleting the whole xampp folder (root folder) there are some files hidden ;)
and also databases ar not in phpmyadmin window, some files are there in the folder (wamp case)
wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data
and there is database files, but the phpmyadmin window in the explorer wont show any databases unless there is any records of them, so it wont show them, but it cant create same files with the same name too ! :)
so delete the whole deleted wamp, xampp folder, then 
reinstall the xampp (or wamp ;) )
I bet this works ;)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can go mysql command line, use `show databases;` to see databases, and `show tables` to tables

Comment: it is showing null but i cant create cities table. Because it is saying to me "xyz.cities table already exists

Answer (score 0):

DB may not be deleted correctly.

Please use `Drop database dbname` and see if that helps

Comment: are you sure about this code. My db's name is XYZ, my table's name is cities

Comment: I am sorry, use it with the DB name. cities

Comment: My bad, use Drop database cities